# Find and copy files filtered by txt file

Tags: windows, powershell, filtering

I was recently introduced to PowerShell and thought this task would be something PowerShell should handle quite well.

I have a `.txt` file containing a string per line. These strings are a substring of a file name. How can I search a directory (recursively) and move all matches to a destination directory?

I looked at `Get-ChildItem` but I could'nt find a way to use files for filter. The filter file can be formatted to whatever is necesary but I only have substrings of the filenames.

Any savy PowerShell users who has a solution?

Comment: You should read up on Select-String, that cmdlet should get you what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
$names = Get-Content names.txt
Get-Childitem C:\path\ -include $names -recurse | move-item X:\targetpath\
```

This would work if your names file had the full filename including extension. Since that is not the case you could do:

```
$names = Get-Content names.txt | % {"*$_*"}
```

Comment: i if I only need to copy them? i tried ´Get-Childitem C:\path\ -include $names -recurse | Copy-Item X:\targetpath\´ but it didn't work

Comment: @d00dle `Get-Childitem C:\path\ -include $names -recurse | % {Copy-Item $_.fullname -destination X:\targetpath\}`